# OWI Robot Arm Circuit Diagram LED question

Tags: led, circuit-design

I was looking at the circuit diagram for the OWI Robot Arm Edge in the manual, and happened to notice the LED. To me, it looks like it has been drawn the wrong way around. But maybe I am wrong. Can someone please confirm that this is actually a mistake. And if it is not a mistake, can you explain the path required to turn the LED on ?
I just need a second opinon.

The manual can be found here:
https://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/owi-535_manual.pdf

See page 33.

Also I have attached that particular page for reference:
[image: OWI Robotic Arm Edge Circuit Diagram]

Thank you very much
Regards
ScottC

Comment: Looks backwards to me, too.

Comment: Thankyou @JRE. It was good to know that the diagram was not right. But after some testing, it turned out that the switch drawn incorrectly. The switch is connected to the + line (in the on position) and not the (-) line as shown in the diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question now is does the drawing match the robot.

The drawing is definitely wrong.

I am willing to bet the LED is installed in the robot the opposite as in the drawing.  It is easy for someone to draw the diode backwards.  But if the LED never worked then someone would have noticed.

If you flip the switch one way the LED should be on, the other way off.  Or visa versa.

I am guessing your LED does not light up no matter which position the switch is in.  This means either the battery is dead or the LED is dead.

Connect a DC volt meter between pins * and -, if it reads 6V then the LED is dead.

I am guessing it will not read 6V but rather something like zero or close to it.

LEDs last forever and rarely die if not abused. Batteries will die, it not a matter of IF they will die, it's a matter of when they will die.

Comment: Thanks @Misunderstood. After doing some continuity testing, I found out the LED is actually drawn correctly. It is the switch that has been drawn incorrectly. When the switch is in the "on" position, it actually connects Pin 6 to the "+" line, and not the "-" line as shown in the "Wired Control Box" Diagram.  This whole split battery connector setup is new to me, so I thought I was missing something. But the fog has lifted. It all makes sense now. But yes, if the switch was connected as per the diagram, then the LED would need to be the other way around. Thank you for your help.